# Web part will not be shown on a wikipage in edit mode

Tags: web-part, telerik

I created a web-part using Telerik AJAX components. If I insert the web part in a sharepoint wiki page, the web-part is not shown. But if the wiki page is beeing saved with "save & close" the web-part will be shown regularly. Back to the edit mode the web-part is not shown. I debugged the web-part, but there is no exception thrown within. I looked in the html of the wiki page in edit mode and I find out that the output of the web-part is packed in following element:

```
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField">
    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField">
        <span dir="none">
            <div class="ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield" style="border: none; ">
                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField_ctl00_ctl00_TelerikScriptManager1"></span>
                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField_ctl00_ctl00_originalEditorContainer" dir="ltr">
                    <input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave" type="HIDDEN" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$WikiField$ctl00$ctl00$TextField_spSave" value=" ... web-part html ... "/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

At Sites or WebPartPages the insertion and the editing works normal as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The webpart or any controls not visible in edit mode may be due to *EditModePanel*. You can check the wiki page layout in SharePoint designer and see if the webpart zone is in *EditModePanel*. The *EditModePanel* has property named *PageDisplayMode* which is Edit by default.

If *PageDisplayMode=Display* the content of *EditModePanel* appear only when the page is in display mode(and not in edit mode)

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">

<!--The content here is not visible in edit mode-->

</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not had this happen with the Telerik controls because I don't use those, but I have had this happen when trying to embed videos or anything else that has scripting or HTML in it into a Wiki type page. There is something in the type of page that prevents it from being stored or loaded properly. I have the exact same results you are experiencing. What I've had to do in the past is actually create a blank html page and embed the script or code there and then use the page viewer web part to show that page on the wiki-style editing page.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Because my client want to use many wiki pages each with an own web part instance.